# Can (Html5,javascript,css3) app will work perfectly on ios and android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, css

I am building a site in Html5 , css3 , javascript and node.js for server side . I want to know that will this app work perfectly on ios and android operating system devices , like ( iphone , ipad , htc , and other android phones ?

Please tell me so that i will proceed to make my app using these technologies .

Thanks,

**Update : **

I don't want to use phonegap or all things like phonegap . I want to make simple app

Comment: you can test device by loading this url in browser http://html5test.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use HTML5 as your platform, you will get almost the exact same visual and functional results on all viewing devices: web, android, and ios. So yes it should work "perfectly".

However note that HTML5 is generally about 10% slower than say coding apps in the native language of the device.

Answer (score 0):

Your website will look just fine on a smart phone if you code it properly. Popular smart phones today can display the web just like you see in on your browser at home (just smaller). Most use webkit as a browser engine.

Answer (score 0):

According to the recent trend, many apps are web based and they do work perfectly. Still you may test in as many devices as possible. According to me, it should work fine. Phone Gap and Appcelerator Titanium are renowned web based mobile development platforms.

If you are creating a website, it should not be a problem in any of the devices.